# NFS gateway configuration - getting exception for NFS3

Tags: hdfs

I am trying to configure NFS gateway to access HDFS data, and followed http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsNfsGateway.html ..

In brief, from the above link, I have followed below steps:

```
sudo service rpcbind start // this will start portmapper and NFS daemons.
sudo netstat -taupen | grep 111 // this confirm that propgram is listenining to port 111
rpcinfo -p ubuntu // tells what all programs all listening for RPC clients.
sudo service nfs-kernel-server start // this will start mountd
rpcinfo -p ubuntu // this should show mountd
sudo service rpcbind stop // this will start system’s portmapper 
sudo netstat -taupen | grep 111 // make sure no other program is running with this port 111. if yes, then use “kill -9 portnum”
sudo ./hadoop-daemon.sh start portmap // start portmap using hadoop program
sudo ./hadoop-daemon.sh start nfs3
sudo mount -t nfs -o vers=3,proto=tcp,nolock 192.168.125.156:/  /var/hdnfs
mount.nfs: **requested NFS version or transport protocol is not supported**
```

**Above error gone** (make sure you stop system NFS calling service nfs-kernel-server stop) and now I am getting below exception for NSF3:

```
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.AuthorizationException): User: srini is not allowed to impersonate root
            at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1410)
            at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1363)
            at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
            at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.getFileLinkInfo(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
            at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:190)
            at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:103)
            at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.getFileLinkInfo(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileLinkInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:712)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileLinkInfo(DFSClient.java:1796)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.nfs.nfs3.Nfs3Utils.getFileStatus(Nfs3Utils.java:58)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.nfs.nfs3.Nfs3Utils.getFileAttr(Nfs3Utils.java:79)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.nfs.nfs3.RpcProgramNfs3.fsinfo(RpcProgramNfs3.java:1723)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.nfs.nfs3.RpcProgramNfs3.handleInternal(RpcProgramNfs3.java:1963)
            at org.apache.hadoop.oncrpc.RpcProgram.messageReceived(RpcProgram.java:162)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:560)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:787)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:281)
            at org.apache.hadoop.oncrpc.RpcUtil$RpcMessageParserStage.messageReceived(RpcUtil.java:132)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:560)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:787)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
            at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462)
            at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443)
            at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:560)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:555)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:107)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:312)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:88)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
            at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
     at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
    2014-06-11 13:51:14,035 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.nfs.nfs3.RpcProgramNfs3: Exception
    org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.AuthorizationException): User: srini is not allowed to impersonate root
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this was a result of the fix that was added in response to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-5804

Specifically, notice Daryn Sharp's comment on 14/Jan/27 about wanting to get away from having different code paths based on isSecurityEnabled().  I take that to mean that the old default behavior was removed and now the new behavior requires a certain amount of configuration. Basically the code was fixed to support security and the configuration/documentation required for the old default unsecure behavior was never updated to reflect the changes. Open Source, but closed doc.

I think there are two new additional pieces of information necessary to get this working -- notice in the documentation you followed the first step to add the "nfsserver proxyuser" details to core-site.xml (note, I think this is needed on the hadoop server side -- particularly the name node -- not so much on the client side where you're running the nfsserver, although by the time I got it working, I had it set everywhere). I followed this step, but changed the values of both settings to * (star) so that "nfsserver" could impersonate anybody when trying to connect from anywhere. Specically, nfsserver needs to be able to impersonate ROOT to get past the issue we were both encountering.

```
<property>
  <name>hadoop.proxyuser.nfsserver.groups</name>
  <value>*</value>
  <description>
         The 'nfsserver' user is allowed to proxy all members of the 'nfs-users1' and 
         'nfs-users2' groups. Set this to '*' to allow nfsserver user to proxy any group.
  </description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hadoop.proxyuser.nfsserver.hosts</name>
  <value>*</value>
  <description>
         This is the host where the nfs gateway is running. Set this to '*' to allow
         requests from any hosts to be proxied.
  </description>
</property>
```

That leads me to the second key piece of information necessary to fix this -- you MUST run the nfs3 server as the userid "nfsserver" -- not as hdfs as the documentation would more easily be interpreted:

> 1. Start mountd and nfsd.
>
> **No root privileges are required for this command. However, ensure that
>   the user starting the Hadoop cluster and the user starting the NFS
>   gateway are same.**
>
> ```
>  hadoop nfs3
>
>  OR
>
>  hadoop-daemon.sh start nfs3
> ```
>
> Note, if the hadoop-daemon.sh script starts the NFS gateway, its log
>   can be found in the hadoop log folder.

I believe this is the second change that was introduced as part of jira 5804.  Most likely, in the past you were supposed to run nfs3 as hdfs and in the event of an unsecure cluster, there was no impersonation going on. Now impersonation appears to be the default, and the only user that it appears you can configure to do impersonation is literally "nfsserver" -- that means you need to provision a user "nfsserver".

So finally, after adding the configuration mentioned above, you need to provision the nfsserver user:

```
#create a system user named nfsserver with hadoop as default group
sudo useradd -r -g hadoop nfsserver
```

and finally start the nfs3 service as that user (in addition to having already started the portmap)

```
sudo -u nfsserver hadoop-daemon.sh start nfs3
```

Comment: I've created a jira ticket to update the documentation (I'm not entirely sure that was the correct route, but at least it's out there now) https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-6717

Comment: Thanks Brandon, I didn't quite realize that the proxyuser property names were dynamic in such a way that there weren't specific valid properties, but there's an infinitely possible set of property names based on the format hadoop.proxyuser.<username>.groups -- I'm now starting to wonder how many of the properties fall into that category and would be better off defined as dynamic properties with the dynamic values called out.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for finding the inconsistency in the document.

With https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-5804, users don't have to start NFS gateway as the same user starting HDFS. (I will fix the user guide soon).

You should always specify the following two properties, regardless of whether the HDFS cluster is secure or not: `hadoop.proxyuser.nfsserver.groups` and `hadoop.proxyuser.nfsserver.hosts`. As pointed out in the user guide, "nfsserver" should be replace by the user who starts NFS gateway.

For secure HDFS cluster, it doesn't matter who starts NFS gateway. It's all about the user in the keytab. In the above two properties, "nfsserver" should be replaced by the user in the keytab.

BTW, if you also post the question in apache user email list, it might get answered more quickly.

I've create a JIRA to track the doc fix: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-6732

Please take a look and comment on the JIRA whether the new doc is still misleading. Thanks!

Comment: I meant apache hadoop user email list.